# Why is it possible to have multiple variables that can change?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    let mut b: i32 = 1;
    let c = &mut b;
    let d = &mut *c;
    *d = 2;
    *c = 1;
}
```

help! Why is it able to compile and run successfully? Why is it possible to have multiple variables that can change?Is the reason for this related to the variable's lifetime?